# Div content should not autoscale

Tags: html, css

I want that content `".content"` in main-div `".box"` scales when the `.content` width is same as `.box` and not smaller.

```css
.box {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 55px auto 40px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 530px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 57px 40px 0;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 800px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="images/image.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `width` to 100% and add `min-width: 530px;` and your `.content` will scale **if width is not smaller than** `.box`

```css
.box {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 55px auto 40px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 530px;
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 57px 40px 0;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 800px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="images/image.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but it not what i mean, i need that content have max width 530px. And when .box is smaller than 530px, .content should goes smaller.

Comment: @user7206180 change `min-width` to `max-width`